# Grails Master-Detail how to manage from a form

Tags: forms, grails, master-detail

Reading about the master-detail structure in using Grails is very confusing.
I've no problem understanding it in DB-terms I think but with models in grails then...
I want, at best, using one form to create the master and redirects to edit-form from where I can add new detail records and show them as a list at the bottom.
In the edit form I click a link that opens the create form of the detail where I enter data and saves it and return to the edit-form wich at the same time updates with a line with the new detail.

I've googled around a lot but can not find anything that helps me understand how I should code the controller to manage this.
It is probably very simple when you have done this once so I hope I could get som help here.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is more a formatting javascript question well it does bind into grails.

What you want is two tabs on a page  so requirements `jquery` `jquery-ui`

If you are running later versions of grails that includes bootstrap then include the jquery-ui line pre bootstrap line in `assets/javgascripts/application.js` otherwise your ui-tabs will not work

`assets/css/application.css`:

```
*= require bootstrap
*= require jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min
```

`javascripts/application.css`

```
//= require jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min
//= require bootstrap
```

With that set you can now use jquery ui

Now you need to create two tabs in a gsp:

```
<!-- first tab at top -->
<div id="myTabs">
    <ul id="topTab">
        <li class="topLi"><a name="#mainTab" >
            <g:message code="mainForm.label"/></a></li>
<li class="topLi"><a name="#mainTab1" >
            <g:message code="anotherTab.label"/></a></li>
        /span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="bottomSection">
        <div id="#mainTab1">
            <g:render template="/path/toMainForm"/>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="#mainTab1">
            <g:render template="/maybe/another/form"/>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- 2nd tabs at bottom -->
<div id="myTabs2">
    <ul id="botTab">
    <!-- make correct url to show all records for the child return that as a template that then renders below -->
       <li class="topTab2A"><a name="#resetPass" href='${createLink(controller:'myController',action:'showChild',)}'>
            <g:message code="reset.password"/></a></li>
<!--3rd tab on page declaration box where above li click will end url on either way not really needed it auto generates content li for above url-->
<ul id="ui-tabs-3" class="property-list"></ul>
    </ul>

<script>
    $('#myTabs,#myTabs2').tabs();
</script>
```

When using tabs always ensure your div's are closed correctly otherwise the page won't load correctly

The first tab at top loads in the template which should contain your master form.

The bottom tab is dynamic tab and will load by default I think the content of the li if not when clicked will action the li href and dynamically load content in a container below it....

You will then need to research how to auto load on a given tab if required etc.

You can also use ajax form methods that loads dynamically into divs.This [example project](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-liveform-example) goes into live form but not really what you asked.

Besides writing the code for such a question I think more research implementation is needed and questions with issues from there

given you the idea play around